# How to take input of space seperated integers in an array (c++)

Tags: c++

Suppose I have to take input of `N` integers (previously provided by the user) and enter them into an array directly. For example

```
cin >> a >> b;
```

is given the input

5 10

5 is assigned to a and 10 to b.

I want a similar thing with arrays. Please help.

Comment: Just loop: for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i) cin >> a[i]; and do not forget error checks.

Comment: ohk... got it thanks for the sollution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the list of integers is in a single line, and there is
nothing else in that line:

```
std::vector<int>
getLineOfInts( std::istream& source )
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline( std::cin, line );
    std::istringstream s( line );
    std::vector<int> results;
    int i;
    while ( s >> i ) {
        results.push_back( i );
    }
    if ( ! s.eof() ) {
        //  Syntax error in the line...
        source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: +1 Especially for the single-line error detection propagation to the source stream. nice touch, sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin>> array[i] >> array2[i];
}
```

Comment: Wrong.  This has undefined behavior all over the place.

Comment: If you have to finish by saying "right?", then its probably not appropriate to answer if you don't even know yourself especially when you answer is so completely wrong.

Comment: Absolutely suits my purpose. Other than the fact that I need only one array. Thanks

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha If your purpose is undefined behavior, so be it, but James has a point. There is zero error checking here (on the stream; at least the array population is upper-bounded), and no indication of how many values were successfully extracted.

Comment: I was just answering based on the OPs question. There should be error checks on seeing on n. And the overall cin function because it has lots of undefined inputs.